# skip assigning value to const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using flux and I found below code is not elegant. Can't I skip the const here? Is there any way to make it one line?

```
static getPropsFromStores(props) {
    const { items } = CrudStore.getState();
    return { items };
}
```

Comment: do you really need to refine items property again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The existing line:

```
const { items } = CrudStore.getState();
```

...is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) equivalent to doing this:

```
const items = CrudStore.getState().items;
```

Whereas this line:

```
return { items };
```

...uses a shorthand [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) equivalent to this:

```
return { items: items };
```

That is, it creates and returns a new object with a property called `items` with a value set to whatever the existing `items` variable is.

So a one-line way of returning an object in the format `{items: items}` without creating the `const` would be:

```
static getPropsFromStores(props) {
    return { items: CrudStore.getState().items };
}
```

Comment: what if I have this `const { items, items_total, items_length } = CrudStore.getState();` will the one-liner still make sense?

Comment: Probably not. I mean, you probably don't want to say `return { items: CrudStore.getState().items, items_total: CrudStore.getState().items_total, items_length: CrudStore.getState().items_length };`. What would the corresponding return statement be in your *existing* code?

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
static getPropsFromStores(props) {
    return {items: CrudStore.getState().items || null};
}
```

Comment: why || null is needed?